# Return data from thread to a separate class

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas

I have a class containing two threads, one which sends data to a server via a socket, and another which receives data from that socket. What I need to do now which im struggling with is:

- From a separate class, iterate through a pandas dataframe one row at a time
- Pass each row to the thread class which sends the data to the server via a socket
- The receive data thread will get a response from the server based on the row that was sent
- Send the response back to the class which is busy iterating through the dataframe so that it can process the response accordingly and then move to the next row

Essentially the part of all of this which im struggling with is figuring out how to pass the server response back to another class. It's easy when dealing with the response in the thread class,...but I don't know how to get that response back to the other class and then move to the next dataframe row.

Basically, im battling to figure out how to have one class running two threads, with a separate class sending and receiving data from the thread class. The thread class works perfectly,...it's just a case of getting the received data out of that class.

Answer (score 0):

1. One way of doing this is broker-subscriber. Let's call the communication class the broker, and the class that wants to receive data the subscriber. What the subscriber should do is call into the broker specifying a (class) method/function to be called when the broker receives data. In the broker, when it receives data it calls this subscriber function - there could even be a list of them.
2. Another way to do this is for the broker to put messages/data into a Queue, and the subscriber to wait on the queue.